# How to encapsulate customized angular component that has events?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm using a [pagination component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples#customization) from ng-bootstrap (which I customized) and I want to reuse the component in other places, without having to rewrite code.

Since the `ngb-pagination` component has a two-way binding property `page`, I need properly to expose that property to the parent component.

I know that the issue is with the component bellow, because if I use the standard one, not inside a component, it works normally.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { faChevronLeft, faChevronRight, faAngleDoubleLeft, faAngleDoubleRight } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  template: `
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
      <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [page]="page" (pageChange)="pageChange" [pageSize]="pageSize" [boundaryLinks]="true">
        <ng-template ngbPaginationFirst>
          <fa-icon class="fas" [icon]="faAngleDoubleLeft" aria-hidden="true"></fa-icon>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbPaginationLast>
          <fa-icon class="fas" [icon]="faAngleDoubleRight" aria-hidden="true"></fa-icon>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbPaginationPages let-page let-pages="pages">
          <li class="ngb-custom-pages-item" *ngIf="pages.length > 0">
              <div class="form-group d-flex flex-nowrap px-2">
                <label id="paginationInputLabel" for="paginationInput" class="col-form-label mr-2 ml-1">Page</label>

                <input #i type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" class="form-control custom-pages-input"
                    id="paginationInput" [value]="page" (keyup.enter)="selectPage(i.value)" (blur)="selectPage(i.value)"
                    (input)="formatInput($any($event).target)" aria-labelledby="paginationInputLabel paginationDescription"
                    style="width: 2.5rem"/>

                <span id="paginationDescription" class="col-form-label text-nowrap px-2">of {{pages.length}}</span>
              </div>
          </li>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbPaginationPrevious>
          <fa-icon class="fas" [icon]="faChevronLeft" aria-hidden="true"></fa-icon>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbPaginationNext>
          <fa-icon class="fas" [icon]="faChevronRight" aria-hidden="true"></fa-icon>
        </ng-template>
      </ngb-pagination>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.scss']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {
  faChevronLeft = faChevronLeft;
  faChevronRight = faChevronRight;
  faAngleDoubleLeft = faAngleDoubleLeft;
  faAngleDoubleRight = faAngleDoubleRight;

  @Input() collectionSize: number = 20;
  @Input() page: number = 1;
  @Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<number>();
  @Input() pageSize: number = 10;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  selectPage(page: string) {
    this.page = parseInt(page, 10) || 1;
  }

  formatInput(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    input.value = input.value.replace('/[^0-9]/g', '');
  }
}
```

And I simple use the component as this (I'm following the [complete table example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#complete)):

```
<app-pagination [collectionSize]="(total$ | async)!" [(page)]="service.page" [pageSize]="service.pageSize">
</app-pagination>
```

So, how can I properly expose the properties and events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit events from component:

```html
<ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="collectionSize" [page]="page" (pageChange)="pageChange.emit($event)" [pageSize]="pageSize" [boundaryLinks]="true">
```

...

```
  selectPage(page: string) {
    this.page = parseInt(page, 10) || 1;
    this.pageChange.emit(this.page);
  }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought that the event would be fired from within the third party component.

Comment: It's separate EventEmitters, you can't overwrite it in a template  `(pageChange)="here you already have $event variable so it's code which passed to callback"`